# SQL server management studio subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I am trying to run this subquery in SQL Server management Studio 2016 but it errors. It works in MySQL. Please advise:

```
select count(distinct company) 
from 
(
select company, sum(net_value_gbp) as last2yr_spend 
from Orders 
where bill_date >='01-Jan-2016' 
group by company)
where last2yr_spend >50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alias is one issue.  But, you should write the query like this:

```
select count(*) 
from (select company, sum(net_value_gbp) as last2yr_spend 
      from Orders  o
      where bill_date >= '2016-01-01'
      group by company
     ) c
where last2yr_spend > 50;
```

Notes:

- Note the alias for the subquery (your immediate problem).
- `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is not needed.  The subquery returns one row per company. `COUNT(DISTINCT)` incurs extra overhead, so a simple `COUNT(*)` is sufficient.
- The date format uses the ISO-standard YYYY-MM-DD.  SQL Server understands this format for most internationalization settings (for 100% completeness, you can drop the hyphens but I like them for readability).
- You would only want `COUNT(company)` (instead of `COUNT(*)`) if `company` were ever `NULL` *and you did not want to count it.

Comment: COUNT(DISTINCT company) and COUNT(*) aren't the same

Comment: @DenisRubashkin Technically correct but irrelevant in this usage. Grouping by Company guarantees that there is one row per company. Therefore, counting distinct company values is exactly the same as counting all rows.

Comment: @SMor, sorry, but you are wrong. We know nothing about data in the table "Orders". If "company" is null, it won't be counted by COUNT(DISTINCT company) or by COUNT(company), whereas it will be counted by COUNT(*), so results can be different as I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

alias your subquery like as below

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT company)
FROM
(
    SELECT company,
           SUM(net_value_gbp) AS last2yr_spend
    FROM Orders o
    WHERE bill_date >= '01-Jan-2016'
    GROUP BY company
) A
WHERE A.last2yr_spend > 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like below :

```
select count(distinct company) 
from 
( select company, sum(net_value_gbp) as last2yr_spend 
from Orders 
where bill_date >= '01-Jan-2016' 
group by company ) 
AS T1
where T1.last2yr_spend > 50
```

You have to use an `ALIAS` for the sub query in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(company) 
from 
(
select company, sum(net_value_gbp) as last2yr_spend 
from Orders 
where bill_date >='01-Jan-2016' 
group by company
having sum(net_value_gbp) > 50) as T1
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to how your code resolves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to subqueries is CTE, which I find slightly more readable. Something like the following:

```
    ;with orders_by_comp as (
          select company, sum(net_value_gbp) as last2yr_spend 
          from Orders  o
          where bill_date >= '2016-01-01'
          group by company)
    select count(distinct company) 
    from orders_by_comp 
    where last2yr_spend > 50;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the filtration on the sum using `having` like this:

```
with cte
AS
(
    select company
    from Orders 
    where bill_date >='01-Jan-2016' 
    group by company
    having sum(net_value_gbp) > 50
) 
select count(distinct company)
from cte;
```